# Pass 2 values into 2 attributes in jQuery

Tags: jquery, node.js, pug

I have a problem with Node.js and Pug engine template.
In ***PHP(HTML)*** I can pass two values into 2 attributes easy:
For example (I pass **row[id]** into button's **id** and **class** attributes):

```
 <?php  
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {  
 ?>  
 <tr>  
 <td><?php echo $row["name"]; ?></td>  
 <td><input type="button" name="view" value="View" id="<?php echo 
 $row["id"]; ?>" class="<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>" /></td>
 </tr>  
 <?php  
 }  
 ?>
```

How can I pass **row.id** into **class** attribute in input type = '**button**' in **Node.js(Pug)**? In example below Pug doesn't define the 'class' attribute.  [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f0dOi.png)

```js
$.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    //contentType: "application/json",
                    url: "select_marks",
                    //data: formData,   //JSON.stringify(formData),
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function (data) {
                        $.each(data, function (i, row) {
                            $('.content').append(
                                 "<input type ='button' id=" + row.id + "class=" + row.id + ">"
                            );

                        });
                    }
                });
```

Comment: give space in `"class` and check

Comment: It did not help (https://i.imgur.com/Ktzlz67.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its probleme of quotes don't forget you have `''`  in your html attributes

If you get good data  in your row I just write like that

```
$('.content').append(
   "<input type ='button' id='" + row.id + "'class='" + row.id + "'/>"
);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/j0z5Lxc4/3/